GET request is not triggered in Nested Routes in Express.js
I created a Nested Route structure with Express.js. There is a house route. This route has a subroute ages. I have defined a GET request function for ages. Of course, I determined this route in functions such as POST and PATCH according to different requests. But only GET request is not triggered for this route. No matter what I did, it didn't work. Maybe I should think more simply, but I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours. I don't know how to search for this on Google. Also GPTs didn't find a solution either. Where exactly is the problem?
index.js file
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const houseRouter = require("./house");
router.use("/house", houseRouter);
module.exports = router;


house.js file
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const ageRouter = require("./ages");

router.use("/ages", ageRouter);
module.exports = router;

ages.js file
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", listAges); //not triggered
router.post("/", addAge); //triggered
router.get("/:id", getAge); //triggered
router.patch("/:id", updateAge); //triggered
router.delete("/:id", deleteAge); //triggered

async function addAge(req, res, next) { //working
  console.log('add age function')
  res.json({success:true});
}

async function listAges(req, res, next) { // not triggered
  console.log('list ages function')
  res.json({success:true});
}

function getAge(req, res, next) { //working
  console.log('get age function')
  res.json({success:true});
}

function updateAge(req, res, next) { //working
  console.log('update age function')
  res.json({success:true});
}

function deleteAge(req, res, next) { //working
  console.log('delete age function')
  res.json({success:true});
}
module.exports = router;


router.get("/", listAges); - not triggered. stuck on pending
router.post("/", addAge); - triggered - working
router.get("/:id", getAge); - triggered - working
router.patch("/:id", updateAge); - triggered - working
router.delete("/:id", deleteAge); - triggered - working

How are you testing this? Nothing here looks inherently wrong.

i tested with postman and my webapp. its stuck on pending. im going crazy. i used router.get("/list", listHouse); instead of router.get("/", listHouse); and its worked. but router.get('/',listHouse) is not triggering. can you try on your machine if its possible please

Two questions... 1) How are you registering the router from index.js with your Express app? 2) Exactly what path are you using in the request?

Tried the same code here. It found working as below:   % curl http://localhost:3000/house/ages
{"success":true}.
% curl http://localhost:3000/house/ages/100
{"success":true}   At server console logged as. list ages function
get age function

The most important file or code is missing... Where do you start from? Can't see any express app and listen command

As you registered routes using /house, all API calls must be started with the prefix. Additionally, there is no default GET handler for the route so GET/POST to /house won't work either.  Based on your definition, all API calls must start with /house/ages. I provided a sample at https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-s7p59y?file=api-test.js

My bad. I changed router.use and router.get order. router.use have to be on the top of router.get or any other request routers. I noticed it when I went to the stackblitz link in the comments. Thanks for your help.
